# Google PubSub ACK not received after processing few messages

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

We are using gcloud pub-sub 1.102.0 release.

Problem :- We have around 8K messages to process. We have 3 subscribers running in 3 different k8s pods and we are doing stream pulling. We are receiving the  ACK for few messages (around 100) from there on wards we are not receiving the ACKs (Verified in GCP console). But the message process is going on in background. And we saw couple of duplicate messages as well. In our use case to process a single message it takes around 40 secs to 1 min. Ack deadline has been configured to 10 mins while creating the subscription.

Flow control configured with 20L.
ExecutorProvider configured with 3.

```
public void runSubsciber() throws Exception {

        Subscriber subscriber = null;
        
        MessageReceiver receiver = new MessageReceiver() {
            public void receiveMessage(PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) {
            messageProcessor.processMessage(message.getData().toStringUtf8());
            consumer.ack();
            }
        };

        try {
            FlowControlSettings flowControlSettings =
                    FlowControlSettings.newBuilder()
                        .setMaxOutstandingElementCount(20L)
                        .build();

            ExecutorProvider executorProvider =
                    InstantiatingExecutorProvider.newBuilder().setExecutorThreadCount(3).build();
            projectId=ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();
            ProjectSubscriptionName subscriptionName = ProjectSubscriptionName.of(projectId, subId);
            subscriber = Subscriber.newBuilder(subscriptionName, receiver)
                                .setExecutorProvider(executorProvider)
                                .setFlowControlSettings(flowControlSettings)
                                .build();
            
            subscriber.addListener(new SubscriberListener(), MoreExecutors.directExecutor());
            subscriber.startAsync().awaitRunning();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            if (subscriber != null) {
                //subscriber.stopAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help us out, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explicitly point your problem? I couldnt conclude what you need with your post. Please try to explain what is the problem and what you would like to have

Comment: Sure @rmesteves,so we have microservice architecture, all apps are communicating through pub sub, we have a batch service in one of the services which pushes around 8K records in json format, which is received by another service whose work is to process these records. As noticed in Gcloud Console, we see a spike in messages upto 8K, and the other service start processing, We have 3 instances running each instance capable of processing 3 messages at a time(Using ExecutorProvider).

Comment: Initially we see a drop in UN-ACK message count but, after few mins, we don't see any drop in the UN-ACK count, but messages are being processed (noticed in our DB) 
So we are trying to figure out what exactly is the problem here, We don't see a drop in UN-ACK count in GCloud console after few mins. We have enabled Flow Control Setting in Subscriber to 20L. We have extended the ACK deadline time to 600 seconds in GCloud console, but still the UN-ACK count is stuck.

Comment: We are not receiving ACK message in PUB-SUB, we can also observe the duplicate messages in our back end system.

Comment: Have you noticed any loss of data in your end?

Comment: No, we didn't notice any data loss but noticed duplicates and UN-ACK count stuck.

Comment: I suggest that you try using the official SDK for PubSub (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java)